# what's the difference of these two ways to create a token account?

Tags: anchor, ata

```
    #[account(init,
      payer = funder,
      token::mint = token_mint_a,
      token::authority = authority)]
    pub token_vault_a: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,


    #[account(init,
        payer = admin,
        associated_token::mint = token_a_mint,
        associated_token::authority = swap_account,
    )]
    pub token_a_account: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
```

Answer (score 7):

The `associated_token` accounts are deterministic and only 1 exist per pair (derived from the wallet PublicKey and token mint PublicKey). You can't use Aux accounts in this context.

With the `token::mint` and `token::authority` context you can use any `TokenAccount` matching that mint and authority. This way you can also read and create Auxilarily or non-associated token accounts.

Comment: By using above steps it's giving an error ( `rent` value not found )

Comment: Which steps? There are no steps described above.